# Javascript Opacity transition for p element

Tags: javascript, css, transition

I have a p element in HTML Code like

```
<p id="errorEmailMsg" hidden>Wrong Mail</p>
```

In javascript I want to make a transition, where it changes the opacity from 0 to 1 in 1second.
I tried to do something like

```
   errorMessage.style.opacity = 0;

        setTimeout(() => {
         errorMessage.style.opacity = 1;
          }, this.animationDelay + 20);
```

How can I achieve this? Thank you and have a nice day :)

Comment: What's the problem with your current solution? Or do you want it to gradually fade in?

Comment: Yes, I want it to look like an effect, but this changes opacity to 1 instantly.

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356679/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a demo with this effect:

https://codepen.io/jordyvd/pen/yLYBvbx

HTML

```html
<p class="p">Some text</p>

<button class="button">Hide it</button>
```

CSS

```css
.p {
  opacity: 1;

  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.p.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

JavaScript

```js
document.querySelector('.button').addEventListener('click', e => {
  document.querySelector('.p').classList.toggle('hidden');
});
```

Click on the button to show/hide the text.

I suggest you look at CSS transitions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

Comment: Thank you, I was looking exactly for this :) It was very helpful.

Comment: Glad I could help =)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `hidden` attribute.

If you want the element to invisible by default use.

```
<p id="errorEmailMsg" style="opacity: 0">Wrong Mail</p>
```